# How to change the default use of detox, so it just doesn't replace spaces by underscores

Tags: filenames, rename

I'm happy with the default usage of [detox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/detox) for sanitizing filenames, except I don't always want to replace whitespace with a single underscore. Would like to replace whitespace with a single space.

Know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `detox`, but I know you can use `tr` to convert your filenames like so:

```
$ echo "a_b__c" | tr -s '_' ' '
a b c

$ echo "a b    c" | tr -s ' '
a b c
```

Obviously replace the `echo` command with your `detox` line.

Comment: The cool essential thing about detox is that it replaces non ascii stuff with the ascii equivalent, so ã or à will become a. Does this do that?

Comment: You can use both `detox` and `tr`.

Comment: i really don't think that would work, detox -r * | tr -s '_' ' ' , right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with detox, but there are other ways to mass-rename files that are more flexible.

With the [Perl-based rename utility](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) (a version of it is available as `rename` on Debian and derivatives, and as `prename` on some other distributions), you can specify arbitrary Perl code to rename files. For example this replaces any sequence of whitespace by a single space in all file names in the current directory:

```
rename 's/\s+/ /g' *
```

This also removes whitespace around punctuation and replaces any other sequence of punctuation and spaces except `.` by an underscore.

```
rename 's/\s* \s*/ /g; s/\s*([^[:alnum:]_. ])[^[:alnum:].]//g' *
```

If you use zsh as your shell, you can use its nifty [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). Put `autoload -U zmv` in your `.zshrc`. This squeezes multiple spaces into a single space in file names in the current directory:

```
zmv '*' '${f//  ##/ }'
```

Comment: The cool essential thing about detox is that it replaces non ascii stuff with the ascii equivalent, so ã or à will become a. Does this do that?

Comment: @fullmooninu No, you'd have to add another transformation (there's probably a Perl library for that but I don't know it offhand), I only showed the removal of “oddball” punctuation.